# How to autoplay HTML5 videos with sound (unmuted) in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, youtube, html5-video, autoplay

Safari and Chrome is not allowing video to autoplay if sound is on by default (unmuted). If you mute the video, it will autoplay, and the user is forced to enable sound. Fine and well, I can live with this.

However, in researching this, I found that YouTube (Safari 11, MacOS High Sierra), is allowing subsequent videos to be played with sound ON if the user turns sound on for a given video. Likewise, if user mutes the video, clicks onto a different video, this video will autoplay muted until user toggles the sound on. I would love to replicate this on a site in which I have created a video gallery of sorts. Each video does live on it's own page, and navigating the gallery will take user to a new page in the browser. This needs to stay the same, for multiple reasons (as opposed to creating a single media element and dynamically changing video source).

Alternatively, is there a way to convince Safari that a user has intentionally clicked a button in order to watch a video, thus allowing autoplay with sound on, when the user is simply clicking a link (in the form of a "Play Video Now" button) to a page with the video embedded?

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately for the user) you cannot override this. If you could autoplay with volume without the user clicking on the video controls directly, then users would be bombarded with videos playing that they didn't know were there. Putting code on a button, mouse hover on the page, or anything like that, does not indicate the user wanted to play the video. Even though your intentions may be good, there are other developers who's intentions aren't...